# How to create a reference to on of my view controllers from my app delegate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

Hi I was wondering, how can I create a reference to one of my view controllers from my app delegate? I'd like to call a specific method (of my view controller) from the delegate when my app enters foreground.

Comment: Which view controller? The one used right before `[window makeKeyAndVisible]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can listen for the `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` notification.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSNotificationCenter *defaultCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [defaultCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationWillEnterForeground:) UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Comment: is the applicationWillEnterForeground: method the same one in the app delegate, of do I need to create this method in my view controller?

Comment: You can change the selector to be whatever you want inside whatever object you want.

Answer (score 3):

1. Make an member ivar pointer of the same class in your *AppDelegate, set it to nil when launching, set its property to "assign".
2. When the specific view controller is created and loaded in the memory, in this controller's viewDidLoad method:

   [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] setThatSpecialContrller:self];
3. When this controller has to be deallocated at some point, you use a similar line of code to again set the pointer to nil.
4. Do a check every time your app is coming from the background to the foreground, if the pointer is not nil, use this not-nil reference to call your specific controller and its method.

Comment: Is this standard behavior, i.e. Apple recommends that you do it this way? Yes, I know this will work, but is it the most elegant way to do it?

Comment: @Altealice: If you want elegance (and possibly, reusability), you can still use my advice, but when implementing, you should strictly follow the Apple highly recommended delegate/protocol pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach, that diwup mentioned, is nicely and shortly described in section "Hooking Up The Left With the Right" in [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1040/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uisplitview-tutorial) tutorial.